# PHP run a background task then notify the right client

Tags: php, background, long-polling

I tried to google before ask, but I'm not able to understand if can be achieved with php the following scenario:
- Run a script that returns immediately to the user. It's job is to run a long task in background
- Notify the right browser client when it finished even if the user has browsed other pages on the same domain / web application

Can i do it with php ?
Can i do with some frameworks like node.js ? 
or with technics like long polling (i do not know a lot about this).
Or ....

I'm searching for someone that can put me on the right way.

Many thanks

Comment: Please remember to choose an answer (if any has proven itself useful)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You could do it with a combination of jQuery/JavaScript and PHP.

For exampel have a row in your database named `NotificationPop` and IF there is value there you can prompt the user just as an example.

Anyhow, its a quite wide question. Just try and fail, if you come into any problems SO will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Kristian interesting point of view. NotificationPop linked to user_id that post the job. but in this way if i'm not in eror, i nedd to perform an ajax request in any page every XX seconds. may i have performance issue ?

Comment: Not really, Javascript is run on the client side, and any decent server will be able to handle a request from any user every 10-15 seconds to php or so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into Websockets. They are what is behind live push notifications or chat rooms. Basically, when something happens (or a process is completed) server-side, the server will "contact" the right user (even if he has changed webpage, but is still on the same domain). The content of the server message is totally up to you. You can do everything you want.
More infos here (try the demo app):
https://www.websocket.org/index.html

Also read this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ to understand why you should not use periodic polling or long polling.

P.s. Please note that in order to use websockets, you need a websocket server running on your server. That is not possible (as far as I know) on a shared hosting, but you need a VPS (virtual private server).

Comment: Thanks Igor, but it's a full cross broswer solution ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Basically, it's what happened when you received my answer here on SO. You saw the red icon in the menu (at the top of the page) with a notification about a new answer to your question. That is websocket magic ;)

Comment: Also, many online multiplayer web games use websockets. Websockets are a "more professional" solution, constant  ajax polling is a "trick/work-around". But, they are both useful depending on the context (= how big your project is)

Comment: Websockets will let you transform your websites/apps with many pro-level features that will set your projects apart from all the others.

Comment: Very interesting Igor. But i do not understand what i need to install on apache server based on Linux CentOS Linux 7.1 ? Thanks

Comment: In this case google is your best friend. For an Ubuntu VPS and a Symfony project I would recommend the WebsocketBundle but your case is different. Sorry. All I can do here in SO is pointing you in the right direction.